# Why can CO₂ be transported dissolved in plasma?

Tags: physiology, homework

Is it because CO<sub>2</sub> is more soluble in water or has it got to do with the alkaline pH of plasma ?I here mean only aqueous CO<sub>2</sub> transport from body cells to lungs.

Comment: can you cite some support for this?  offhand i would think that CO2 is more soluable in acid - it forms bicarbonate carbonic acid.

Comment: At what level do you mean? Are you talking about transporting from a source to a sink? CO2 is soluble in pure water, and as atmospheric partial pressures of CO2 are going to be lower than physiologic levels, any reversible buffering is just going to aid in transporting CO2 "downhill".

Comment: By *Dissolved state* do you mean just the aqueous $\ce{CO2}$ molecules or those that are in form of $\ce{H2CO3}$ and $\ce{HCO3-}$ (free or associated) also?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Solubility of gases is affected by the chemical nature of the gas. Acidic oxides dissolve in water readily because they react to form acids. The high pH can keep the acid dissociated thereby pulling the gas-acid equilibrium towards acid. CO2 is more soluble, in general, than nitrogen and oxygen because it is polar (however it lacks net dipole moment)

Answer (score 3):

The bulk of CO<sub>2</sub> is transported as bicarbonate/carbonic acid.  The conversion between CO<sub>2</sub> and carbonic acid is catalyzed by carbonic anhydrase in red blood cells, otherwise the conversion would be very slow. The bicarbonate is then shuttled out of the RBCs and into the blood plasma. The CO<sub>2</sub> (gas) in blood plasma accounts for <10% of CO<sub>2</sub> transport, and the solubility isn't that much different from that in water.

Source: Guyton and Hall Textbook on Medical Physiology

Comment: about the same amount of CO2 is transported by hemoglobin...

Comment: Hemoglobin actually doesn't carry very much CO2, as it doesn't have a dedicated spot to carry it.  There is a binding site on the protein, but its purpose is to facilitate the release of extra oxygen to metabolically active tissues.

Comment: ... in fact only 10% of it!  see wikipedia: Hemoglobin.

Comment: Haemoglobin cannot bind CO2. It is not a good ligand for metal co-ordination complexes. However carbon monoxide is a strong ligand and can form carbonyls with metals, which accounts for its toxicity.

Comment: @shigeta - I thought you were saying hemoglobin carries as much CO2 as bicarbonate transport does...my mistake!

Comment: @WYSIWYG Hemoglobin does have a CO2 binding site - its not the haem site though.  LMGTFY: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemoglobin#Binding_for_ligands_other_than_oxygen